# MS Teams How to get the MS Teams connectorID and webHook ID from a Team Channel?

Tags: lambda, webhooks, microsoft-teams

How do you get the connectorID and webhook ID (teams_webhook_id) from MS Teams? I'm trying to construct a webhook uri to send a POST request (notifications) to MS Teams. Looking for a reference to the webhook url format

The last part of the format teams_webhook_id is not documented very well on where to fetch/get the details form?

```
https://outlook.office.com/webhook/daxxxxx@d77xxxx/IncomingWebhook/23b0ef39058040339562b8cba6183e67/ca74xxxx-xxxx
```

Where to get the connectorID and webHookID?

Example

````
```
team_webhook_id = ??
teams_webhook_url = "https://outlook.office.com/webhook/"
teams_webhook_uri = teams_webhook_url+groupId+@+tenantId+teams_webhook_id


response = http.request('POST', teams_webhook_uri, 
                         body=webhook_encoded_body)
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the webhook in MS Teams is `https://outlook.office.com/webhook/{groupId}@{tenantId}/IncomingWebhook/{connectorId}/{webHookId}`

Unlikes slack, MSTeams cannot send a notification with to the channel name but needs a webhook

You can get this from MS Teams -> go to team name -> channel name -> connectors and click on configure.

Reference and Further reading: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-lambda-webhooks-chime-slack-teams/

Answer (score 1):

You get them when you create the actual webhook. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#add-an-incoming-webhook-to-a-teams-channel) for how to do so.